# Binary number theory

Tags: binary, universal-property

I want to know if there exists some book about "Binary number theory", I'm interesting in this because there many problems of ICPC about this topic.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what's an ICPC ?

Comment: The ACM-ICPC International Collegiate Programming Contest

Comment: ummm.then what do you think "binary number theory" would be about?

Comment: perhaps you could give  links to summaries of past contests, in which the problems you are thinking about were prominent.

Comment: https://icpcarchive.ecs.baylor.edu/external/65/6527.pdf

Comment: Search for "binary representation" and you'll find a lot of helpful information. I'm not sure there's an entire book, but you might find one mentioned. http://www.google.com/search?q=binary+representation

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that what you want is number theory, but before college level courses on that. so, try [ONE](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/081763245X) and [TWO](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0817645276).

Also, try the Project Euler problems. Those are meant to be done by yourself, experimented with, and end up with a computer program that takes no more than a minute of people time to execute. Meanwhile, you learn mathematics principles of about the correct depth for you. Unfortunate that people post the problems here, they are for self-study, hybrid mathematics/programming.

Comment: Thanks so much for the recommendation

Answer (score 0):

"Binary" is just one particular way of representing a number.  The subject is "number theory".